# How to draw an inner div over an outer div using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to draw an inner div over an outer div for scrolling purposes. How can I change my CSS to fix this?

HTML code:

```
<div class="sliderPath">
     <div class="slider"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.sliderPath {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
}


 .slider {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background:#50c2de;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ImSonuGupta/0bx6uwyn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting top position to small value:

```
.slider {
  border-radius: 4px;
  background:#50c2de;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 3px;               //added this
  }
```

And also set position: relative on parent:

```
.sliderPath {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;     //added this
}
```

[updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqsf9fmm/1/)

Comment: I have already tried this but it won't work when i will  draw multiple sliders
https://jsfiddle.net/ImSonuGupta/0bx6uwyn/2/

Comment: @imSonuGupta please try it now, I've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Simply make `.sliderPath` the base position for its childs, with `position:relative`, and make `.slider` `top` 100% off its parent height.

```
.sliderPath {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #73AD21;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    margin: auto;
    position:relative;
}

.slider {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background:#50c2de;
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    top:100%
}
```

---

**EDIT**

if you need multiple slides, just add margin-bottom to `.sliderPath` equal to `.slider` height. So it would be:

```
.sliderPath {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 20%;
  margin: auto;
  position:relative;
  margin-bottom:50px;
}
```

Comment: it won't work if i will draw multiple sliders
https://jsfiddle.net/ImSonuGupta/0bx6uwyn/2/

Comment: In the case you need multiple, you have some options: Define a margin  for `.sliderPath` = `.slider` height. Make `.slider` floated with a `:before` pseudo-element that mimics the height of `.sliderpath` and has a `clearfix`. Or, in the best non-hack way use some jquery. But won't be a CSS solution. Wich would you pick?

Comment: Just did a few tests, and the margin-bottom seems to be the best solution. Given you have `.slider` height.